# How can I change form "spaces" into "%" to fix my search bar?

Tags: php, mysql, search, urlencode, str-replace

My PHP/Mysql search bar needs each individual word to have a "%" in-between to get it to work.

Does anyone know how to replace the SPACES sent to the url with a "%" instead of the default "+"?

Eg:
"...search.php?find=testing%speed..."

instead of:
"...search.php?find=testing+speed..."

Thanks Heaps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change how your search bar works by replacing the searches with +?

Comment: That saves the space, yet I need to convert the space into a "%".

Comment: i hope you mean %20 instead of +, and not a % glob to feed your LIKE query

Comment: I remember something to do with the Php or Mysql installed that chooses by default if the spaces become a "+" or "%20"

Comment: This sounds more like you have a huge SQL injection hole in your code. Fix that at first, and you "issue" will just go away. There is nothing preventing people to manually write URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use preg_replace

try:

```
$pattern = '/\s/';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, '%', $your_url);
```

This is a regular expression to replace spaces(\s), with '%'.

And as guido said, you might need %20

Comment: I tried:
$find = $_GET['find'];
$find = preg_replace(" ", "%", $find);
But I have never used that function and its probably used incorrectly.

Comment: I suggest using `str_replace(' ','%',$find)` for that (maybe you got confused with that), instead of a regex

Comment: Ah you legend! using the preg_replace like you recommended works perfectly. Thanks heaps.